# Why . is getting excluded in word boundary in regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
\b[_\.][0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{0,}[_]{0,}\b
```

My input string is:

1. `_49791626567342fYbYzeRESzHsQUgwjimkIfW`
2. `.49791626567342fYbYzeRESzHsQUgwjimkIfW`

I would assume that it matches `1.` and `2.`, but it is only matching in the first scenario. Can you help me find the mistake in the regex?

Comment: change the regex font to normal form.

Comment: There's no word boundary before the `.`. Why would there be? There's no word before or after it.

Comment: Issue is at [_\.] only..dont know why

Answer (score 3):

A word boundary is a border between a word character (letters, digits, underscore) and either a non-word-character or the start or end of the string. So there simply is no word boundary between dot (non-word-character) and the start of the string.

You can use an anchor in this case, to signal the start of the string, like

```
^[_\.][0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{0,}[_]{0,}$
```

You can also shorten your regex a bit by using `*` and `+` quantifiers and avoiding unnecessary escape sequences, as suggested by [Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto)

```
^[_.][0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*_*$
```

You can also use lookahead and lookbehind (if available) to build yourself a custom boundary.

Comment: This can be reduced to: `^[_.][0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*_*`

Comment: @Toto yes it can (included it into my answer) but it doesn't make a functional difference, so I didn't really focus on that. (also what is reduced for you, might be less readable for someone else)

Comment: Sure, there're no functional difference, but it's really much more readable to have `_*` instead of `[_]{0,}`.